# Lenovo Legion 7 16ACHg6 no sound from speakers and black screen after waking up from suspend

Tags: nvidia, sound, 22.04, lenovo

**OS:** Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

**Laptop:** Lenovo Legion 7 16ACHg6

**Nvidia driver:** 535.161.07

**Problems:**

1. no sound from speakers at all
2. when on battery and using dynamic mode for graphics, then when waking
   up from suspend, there is black screen, keyboard backlight is
   working and NumLock button works too, but no error message, just
   black screen

from `journactl` I've found these lines:

```
22:59:52 legion kernel: cs35l41-hda i2c-CLSA0100:00-cs35l41-hda.0: System Suspend not supported
22:59:52 legion kernel: cs35l41-hda i2c-CLSA0100:00-cs35l41-hda.1: System Suspend not supported
23:01:27 legion pulseaudio[3948]: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
```

```
uname -a
Linux legion 6.5.0-25-generic #25~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Feb 20 16:09:15 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have read dozen of questions here about Cirrus module and about 'black screen' but could not figure out solution. I am currently using Ubuntu with Wayland but had same issues with X server as well.